# С++. Как наполнить шаблонный класс разным содержимым

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Всем здравствуйте.
Есть шаблон класса

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

struct PORT0{
    struct IOCR0 {  } ;
    struct IOCR4 {  } ;
    struct IOCR8 {  } ;
    struct IOCR12 {  } ;
};
struct PORT1{
    struct IOCR0 {  } ;
    struct IOCR4 {  } ;
    struct IOCR8 {  } ;
};

template<typename Port, std::uint8_t pinNum>
struct Pin
{
  using PortType = Port;
  constexpr Pin() = default;

  static void SetMode(uint8_t mode){
  using IOCR = typename std::conditional<(pinNum < 4), typename PortType::IOCR0,
                typename std::conditional<((pinNum >= 4) && (pinNum < 8)), typename PortType::IOCR4,
                typename std::conditional<((pinNum >= 8) && (pinNum < 12)), typename PortType::IOCR8,
                typename PortType::IOCR12
                >::type >::type >::type;
  }
};

int main()
{
    using LED = Pin<PORT1, 0>;
    LED::SetMode(0);
}
```

Нужно что-бы в зависимости от значения pinNum выбирался разный класс для IOCR, частично получилось реализовать с помощью std::conditional но проблема в том что не во всех передаваемый классах Port есть  например PortType::IOCR12, если использовать как показано выше std::conditional, компилятор ругается что нету такого метода в передаваемом классе. 
 Как можно исключить из компиляции классы если их нету в передаваемом классе? Хотел использовать if constexpr но его можно использовать только в шаблонных функциях. Возможно enable_if поможет, но как это правильно реализовать не знаю.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: В приведенном фрагменте компилятор ругается разве что из-за отсутствия необходимых инклюдов, да из-за рандомного `> > >::type;` приводите [mcve] *"Хотел использовать if constexpr но его можно использовать только в шаблонных функциях."* - так тут только такие и есть.

Comment: @user7860670 Исправил, надеюсь сейчас всё понятней.

Comment: Так а с `if constexpr` что не так?

Comment: @user7860670 при использовании if constexpr ошибка  error: expected '(' before 'constexpr'
     if constexpr(pinNum < 4) плюс область видимости  using обьявленого в if ограничена.

Comment: это говорит о том, что сборка производится не в режиме C++17

Comment: @user7860670 Действительно, извините, но как расширить область видимости IOCR,     if constexpr(pinNum < 4)
    using IOCR = typename PortType::IOCR0;,

Comment: выносите это наружу в отдельный типаж

Comment: @user7860670 В отдельный типаж, каким образом?

Comment: @user7860670 Если вынести условие за пределы SetMode, будет ошибка компиляции,  if constexpr можно использовать только внутри функций. Можете привести пример, как вы видите решение данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот такой вариант будет работать даже в С++11. Хотя тут по идее можно упростить заменив именованные порты на шаблоны вида `Port<index>` и т.п

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

struct PORT0{
    struct IOCR0 {  } ;
    struct IOCR4 {  } ;
    struct IOCR8 {  } ;
    struct IOCR12 {  } ;
};
struct PORT1{
    struct IOCR0 {  } ;
    struct IOCR4 {  } ;
    struct IOCR8 {  } ;
};

template<typename x_Port, typename ::std::uint8_t x_pin_num, bool x_enabled = true> class
t_IOCR_Impl;

template<typename x_Port, typename ::std::uint8_t x_pin_num> class
t_IOCR_Impl<x_Port, x_pin_num, (x_pin_num < 4)> final
{
    public: using t_Type = typename x_Port::IOCR0;
};

template<typename x_Port, typename ::std::uint8_t x_pin_num> class
t_IOCR_Impl<x_Port, x_pin_num, ((4 <= x_pin_num) && (x_pin_num < 8))> final
{
    public: using t_Type = typename x_Port::IOCR4;
};

template<typename x_Port, typename ::std::uint8_t x_pin_num> class
t_IOCR_Impl<x_Port, x_pin_num, ((8 <= x_pin_num) && (x_pin_num < 12))> final
{
    public: using t_Type = typename x_Port::IOCR8;
};

template<typename x_Port, typename ::std::uint8_t x_pin_num> using
t_IOCR = typename t_IOCR_Impl<x_Port, x_pin_num>::t_Type;

template<typename Port, std::uint8_t pinNum>
struct Pin
{
  using PortType = Port;
  constexpr Pin() = default;

  static void SetMode(uint8_t mode){
  using IOCR = t_IOCR<Port, pinNum>;
  }
};

int main()
{
    using LED = Pin<PORT1, 0>;
    LED::SetMode(0);
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/aEMvoP)

Comment: Как всё просто, специализация шаблона, точно, спасибо. В с++20 появились концепты, ими кажется тоже можно решить задачу.

Comment: @Aleksej концепты служат для несколько иных целей и не добавляют в язык ничего принципиально нового.

Comment: компилятор ругается на условие в шаблонных классах, "говорит список аргументов шаблона для частичной специализации содержит нетипизированный аргумент, тип которого зависит от параметра шаблона" так действительно можно?

Comment: @Aleksej приводите [mcve]

Comment: При компиляции кода что вы привели выше  ошибка main.cpp:20:49: error: template argument '(x_pin_num < 4)' involves template parameter(s)
 t_IOCR_Impl<x_Port, x_pin_num, (x_pin_num < 4)> final
                                                                                     ^~~~~  и так для каждого условия. Если в онлайн компиляторе что вы привели выше изменить тип компилятора на ARM GCC 8.3.1 ошибка воспроизводится. Похоже дело в компиляторе.

Comment: @Aleksej Хмм, ну тогда можно попробовать обернуть `bool` в тип `typename x_enabled = ::std::true_type`, `::std::integral_constant<bool, (x_pin_num < 4)>`

Comment: Работает, шаблоны всё-таки сложная штука.